# How to filter by date with Solarium

Tags: php, solr, solarium

How can I add a clause in php Solarium to filter by date?
like omit all the results where date > today.

```
$query = $client->createSelect();
$query->createFilterQuery('myDateField')->setQuery(
    sprintf('myDateField:%s', /*WHAT TO PUT HERE?*/)
);
```

thanks

Comment: try &fq=date:[2020-11-10T00:00:00Z TO NOW]&sort=date desc

Comment: this is the syntax for SOLR, I'd need to use it in Solarium and filter a resultset. I updated my question for clarity.

Comment: The query should work the same. `[2020-11-10T00:00:00Z TO NOW]` in the query part. It's one of the examples in the Solarium manual (just for a regular integer value): `$query->createFilterQuery('maxprice')->setQuery('price:[1 TO 300]');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would be in solarium for solr would be :

```
$query->createFilterQuery('myDateField')->setQuery(
    sprintf('myDateField:[2020-11-10T00:00:00Z TO NOW]')
);
```